# Count how many times a condition is triggered in MySQL into a time lapse

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timelapse

I have this sql table

```
     temp_int   hum_int   datetime             
      25.9        84   2013-10-01 11:30:00  
      26.4        81   2013-10-01 11:45:00  
      25.3      88.1   2013-10-02 11:00:00  
      26.3      85.8   2013-10-02 11:15:00  
      27.1      83.5   2013-10-02 11:30:00  
      27.9      81.9   2013-10-02 11:45:00  
      28.8        81   2013-10-02 12:00:00  
      26.1      80.3   2013-10-02 19:15:00  
      25.8      81.6   2013-10-02 19:30:00
```

So I want count number of times the condition is exceeded for **45** minutes.
The condition is **temp_int>=25 and hum_int>80**, so for this example dataset must give me 1 as a result:

First one=     `2013-10-02 11:00:00`

Second one=    `2013-10-02 11:45:00`

For instance:

[image]

For this set, mysql must return one row, for instance when start the time window.

Comment: I presume you can change the SQL or whatever generates this to remove all the extraneous formatting and make a simple CSV?

Comment: Ok, is not a Specific data format is mysql query data result

Comment: Manu, every row in your example data is over those thresholds? In your real data is there rows at every 15 minute interval?

Comment: Hi @OGHaza there are a lot of rows, each 15 minutes, every hour, day, ..

Comment: Ok, and say at `00:00` they go over the threshold, then they stay above the threshold until `02:00`, what time values would you expect in the result set?

Comment: Each 15 minutes I've a datalog register. But I need how much times happened into a time interval of 45 minutes continuous.

Answer (score 0):

to accomplish this i had to create extra column ID to let it easy to handle between rows , you should also done this. and fill it with values like that :

```
id  temp_int   hum_int   datetime             
 1    25.9        84   2013-10-01 11:30:00  
 2    26.4        81   2013-10-01 11:45:00  
 3    25.3      88.1   2013-10-02 11:00:00  
 4    26.3      85.8   2013-10-02 11:15:00  
 5    27.1      83.5   2013-10-02 11:30:00  
 6    27.9      81.9   2013-10-02 11:45:00  
 7    28.8        81   2013-10-02 12:00:00  
 8    26.1      80.3   2013-10-02 19:15:00  
 9    25.8      81.6   2013-10-02 19:30:00
```

and then run this query

```
select  t1.`datetime`
from contacts t1
inner join contacts t2
on t2.id = (t1.id + 1)
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,t1.`datetime`,t2.`datetime`) > 45
and t1.temp_int>=25 and t1.hum_int>80
```

[**WATCH DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6673c/1)

Comment: It doesnt do what It has to do. As you see: at 2013-10-02 11:00:00 start the restriction (temp_init, hum_int) and it continues 45 minutes and then it continues. I need know how many times of 45 minutes groups  have happend.

Comment: i dont understand how you count and how it must be the restriction. explain well pls

Comment: Well, I have a time serie, for instance: 2013-10-02 11:00:00,  2013-10-02 11:15:00, 2013-10-02 11:30:00, 2013-10-02 11:45:00, 2013-10-03 11:00:00, 2013-10-03 11:15:00,...  And I know that this serie has a 45 minutes continuous group from  2013-10-02 11:00:00 to 2013-10-02 11:45:00, because the next data in time serie is another day (so, not can be continuous)